# Create container module - export * as x from 'y'

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have this in a module:

```
export const Category = require('./category');
export const Roles = require('./roles');
export const FunctionalTeams = require('./functional-team');
export const WorkSteams = require('./workstream');
```

I tried changing it to TS imports:

```
export * as Category from './category';
export * as Roles from './roles';
export * as FunctionalTeams from './functional-team';
export * as WorkSteams from'./workstream';
```

but that doesn't work, tsc doesn't even recognize that syntax, I see these errors:

```
models/enums/index.ts(17,22): error TS1005: ';' expected.
models/enums/index.ts(17,27): error TS1005: ';' expected.
models/enums/index.ts(18,10): error TS1005: 'from' expected.
models/enums/index.ts(18,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
models/enums/index.ts(18,19): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using two-liners, such as:

```
import * as Category from './category';
export Category;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either export all the elements from a module like below (no renaming allowed):

```
export * from '../file.ts';
```

Or you can export specific elements and rename them as you see fit:

```
export {Class1, Class2 as Class3} from '../file.ts';
```

Documentation for re-exports: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: yeah seems like you can't do it in one line